# How f(n-1) + f(n-2) together call to f(n)?

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

How both f(n-1) + f(n-2) works at same time over f(n) only in recursion method of fibonacci numbers ? I cannot understand it please help. How with adding f(n-1) + f(n-2) calls over f(n)?
Thanks.

Comment: Draw it up on paper! Step through actual code with a debugger!

Comment: Try to understand _stack_ structure first.

Comment: No, "*`f(n-1) + f(n-2)` together*" don't call `f(n)`, it's the other way round. The call to `f(n)` will call the other two in order to compute the fibonacci.

Comment: I think Bergi understand my question properly. So please elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the flow on paper & you will get a better way to visualize the process. Here is an tree structure that will be help for better understand.

[image]

For more information, you can read [this](https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e) artical.